# async/await w/ koa 2 & mongoose

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-6, koa

I'm currently playing with Koa 2, with the async/await feature. Let's say I have 2 routes, both querying on the DB. One query is a regular & easy one. On the second one here is what I did:

```
q.$where = `function() {
  var d = new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 2000);
  while (d > (new Date())) { }; return true;}`
return await this.findOne(q)
```

The `$where` adds a **2 seconds delay** to simulate a slow query. If I request twice this route (the slow one) like that:

```
$.get('/api/users/slug')
$.get('/api/users/slug')
```

The server logs:

```
<-- GET /api/users/slug
--> GET /api/users/slug 200 2,004ms 183b // after 2sec
<-- GET /api/users/slug
--> GET /api/users/slug 200 2,003ms 183b // after 4sec
```

We see the the second request hits the server after 2 seconds.
Whereas if I request:

```
$.get('/api/users/slug')
$.get('/api/other/route')
```

The other route is doing the same things but without the delay, the server says:

```
<-- GET /api/users/hugo
<-- GET /api/other/route
--> GET /api/other/route 200 3ms 183b
--> GET /api/users/hugo 200 2,004ms 183b
```

We see the the second request hits the server right after the first one.

I actually expected the first test to give me

```
<-- GET /api/users/slug
<-- GET /api/users/slug
--> GET /api/users/slug 200 2,004ms 183b
--> GET /api/users/slug 200 2,003ms 183b
```

So the whole thing would have take 2 seconds instead of 4. Do you know why it doesn't?

It's a pretty long question, I tried to give you all the relevant informations. Thx!

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easier to simulate the delay by using `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));`?

Comment: Yes sure! I wanted to simulate a slow mongodb request, without chaging the JS code, but the result would have the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more tests I figured out that it comes from the browser (and Chrome in this case), final test:

```
$.get( "http://localhost:3000/api/users/slug") // 1
$.get( "http://localhost:3000/api/users/slug") // 2
$.get("http://localhost:3000/api/other/route") // 3
$.get("http://localhost:3000/api/other/route") // 4
```

Requested with Chrome:

```
<-- GET /api/users/slug // 1
<-- GET /api/other/route // 3
--> GET /api/users/slug 200 2,004ms 183b
<-- GET /api/users/slug // 2
--> GET /api/other/route 200 2,004ms 183b
<-- GET /api/other/route // 4
--> GET /api/other/route 200 2,003ms 183b
--> GET /api/users/slug 200 2,015ms 183b
```

It takes 4 secondes (2sc for 1 & 3 + 2sc for 2 & 4). Requested on Firefox:

```
<-- GET /api/users/slug // 1
<-- GET /api/users/slug // 2
<-- GET /api/other/route // 3
<-- GET /api/other/route // 4
--> GET /api/users/slug 200 2,004ms 183b
--> GET /api/users/slug 200 2,015ms 183b
--> GET /api/other/route 200 2,003ms 183b
--> GET /api/other/route 200 2,004ms 183b
```

And it all takes 2 seconds.

Well, it finally has nothing to do with the server (or node, koa, async), it's just the way the browser handles the requests.